# MIPS .word clarification

Tags: cpu-word, mips

If I write

```
.data                        
 one:   .word 1
```

and later in my program I write

```
beq $a3,one,loop1
```

will it work? ie does beq late labels as arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You will have to load the word into a register first: `lw $t0, one`

MIPS is a load/store architecture. The only way to get a value from memory is to use a load instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Using `beq $a3, 1, basecase` is **totally wrong**.  It happened to work for you because register 1 ($at) happened to equal register $a3. This co-incidence is not too surprising because `$at` is used as a temporary register by the MIPS assembler.

The binary encoding for the `beq` instruction uses: bits 31:26 for the op-code (`000100`); bits 25:21 for the first register number; bits 20:16 for the second register number; bits 15:0 for the address offset.  There is no provision for an immediate value for this instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I ended up doing this:

```
beq $a3, 1, basecase    #check if value at $a3 is equal to 1
```

this syntax also works. Do not necessarily have to have 2 registers.